# Drill Fast vs Drill Slow

Tags: drill

When should I drill fast and when should I drill slow, when drilling holes on metal pieces? and what are the advantages and disadvantages for both of them?

(Suppose a corded drill have 10 speed level, you may assume that drill fast means drilling at speed 7 or above, while drill slow will be at speed 3 or below)

Comment: Look up drill speed chart on Google images: https://www.google.com/search?q=drill+speed+chart&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwibvc21ubvQAhWIzIMKHS-ECNMQsAQIIw&biw=1773&bih=886 There's a lot of variables here depending on exact metal, drill alloy and coatings. Find the chart that applies to your situation. Drill too fast in stainless, and you'll temper/harden the stuff to the point of non-drillability. Too slow on most metals, and you'll only dull your bit. Drilling granite, not a metal, it's pretty easy to get enough frictional heating to melt your drill bit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most of the time you'll be better off using slow speed, high feed: i.e. slow drill speed and press hard. Bigger the hole the slower the speed. Small holes you might get away with a medium speed, anything over 10mm you need to be real slow. Judge your speed by your swarf. Nice long curls are perfect, but you'll need good bits.

Oh, and don't forget to use lube. Water in a squirty bottle gets used a lot around here if the proper stuff has gone walkies.

Drilling dry overheats and kills bits faster than anything.

Remember to dry off though if you don't want rust.